# Google Calendar API: Add attendee via service account not working

Tags: api, service, calendar, account, quota

i try to add attendes to a google-calendar-event.
If i log in via my personal account (OAuth2), everything works.
But if i try to do this via a service-account, i got the error:

```
{
   "code": 403,
   "errors": [
       {
           "domain": "usageLimits",
           "reason": "quotaExceeded",
           "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
       }
   ]
}
```

I found a blog, where someone wrote, that you need quota to add attendees
and service-accounts dont't have any quota. This should be the issue.

But this is no solution for me, because i want to add some attendees by a
server-to-server-request. It's only about 2-5 attendees and only one or two
times a day.

Is there any other way to add attendees by a server-to-server-request?

Best regards,

alex

Answer (score 0):

The reason is **general issue when creating calendar events with attendees using a service account**, see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/141704931).

Right now the best workaround would be letting the service account impersonate a user, so it looks like it was the user and not the service account who created this event.